# Enzyme Shallow Rendering and Material-UI: You are providing a function without a theme in the context

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I'm very new to tests and I am trying to implement them in an existing react project.
I have a button component which needs a theme context.
I understand that to provide this theme in the test file you need to place the component in a theme provider.
However even after I have done this, and tried every possible variation of passing the theme as context that I have found, I still get the error:

> "Material-UI: the `styles` argument provided is invalid.
>         You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
>         One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider."

My button.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import red from "@material-ui/core/colors/red"
import grey from "@material-ui/core/colors/grey"
import Button from "../../components/basics/button"
import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme"
import EnzymeAdapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16"

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new EnzymeAdapter()});

let theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: red[600],
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: grey[500],
      light: grey[300]
    },
  },
  typography:{
    button: {
      fontWeight: "500",
      textTransform: 'none',
    }
  }
})
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

test("Returns a valid button", () => {

  const wrapper = shallow(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button type="normalWithIcon" variant="outlined" icon="GetApp" buttonText="Download" color="primary"/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )

  const b = wrapper.find(Button).dive().find("[data-test='component-button']")

  console.log(b)

  expect(b.length).toBe(1)

})
```

And this error is getting called when the button component tries to make the styles:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'secondary' of undefined

      24 |   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      25 |     root: {
    > 26 |       color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
         |                            ^
      27 | 
      28 |       '&$disabled': {
      29 |         color: theme.palette.secondary.light
```

I am running the latest versions of React, Jest and Enzyme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, use `mount` instead of `shallow` whenever you need to `dive` into the shallow rendered component.

According to the [description of `dive` in the Enzyme docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html), it will:

> Shallow render the one non-DOM child of the current wrapper, and return a wrapper around the result. It must be a single-node wrapper, and the node must be a React component.

So, `dive` returns a new shallow wrapper around the child of `Button` which no longer includes `ThemeProvider` or `Button` itself. As such, use `mount` instead if you're going to test something rendered inside `Button`.

Comment: Im a bit confused the page that you linked uses shallow as the example. And when I swapped the shallow for the mount I'm getting "wrapper.find(...).dive is not a function".

Comment: `mount` does not have `dive`. Instead, use `find` on the component you need.

Comment: Yes! I could've sworn that I tried that before but a simple .find() works with the basic theme provider. Thank you!